# Is it possible to enable/disable Bluetooth tethering programmatically on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, tethering

Is it possible to enable/disable Bluetooth tethering programmatically on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to ling.s's answer, Bluetooth tethering can be controlled programmatically. Refer to the sample code that I posted at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22668259/705483

Replace "isTetheringOn" with "setBluetoothTethering" in the reflection call and pass in a boolean param (also see the first thread linked in that answer).

Answer (score -1):

Make this function in thread

```
BluetoothAdapter btadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                   btadapter.disable();
               btadapter.enable();
```

may it helps u.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This code just restarts a BT adapter, and it doesn't related to tethering.

Comment: No. I'm asking about Bluetooth tethering (Internet sharing over Bluetooth)