# How to check Bluetooth tethering status programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, tethering

Is there any way to find out bluetooth tethering is enabled or disabled programmatically in Android 2.3+(any version after 2.3+)?

I am not asking to enable/disable it, but only to know if it is enabled currently or not.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that BluetoothPan (Personal Area Networking) is the keyword for tethering. I pored over the API documentation and Android source code, but the brief examples in the comments were misleading. This poster provided an example but I had trouble with it initially:
[Android BluetoothPAN to create TCP/IP network between Android device and Windows7 PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692368/android-bluetoothpan-to-create-tcp-ip-network-between-android-device-and-windows)

I tried various other methods including checking the IP address of the BT device. However no Bluetooth network device exists, so there's no IP to check.
[Detect USB tethering on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509924/detect-usb-tethering-on-android)

Back to the BluetoothPan code... The example in the first thread was incomplete (no ServiceListener implementation). I tried a standard one but the *isTetheringOn* proxy call failed. The crucial piece is that the *onServiceConnected()* callback needs at least one line of code or the compiler optimizes it away. It also shouldn't disconnect the proxy like most other examples have.  Here's the working code:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
Class<?> classBluetoothPan = null;
Constructor<?> BTPanCtor = null;
Object BTSrvInstance = null;
Class<?> noparams[] = {};
Method mIsBTTetheringOn;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Context MyContext = getApplicationContext();
    mBluetoothAdapter = getBTAdapter();
    try {
        classBluetoothPan = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothPan");
        mIsBTTetheringOn = classBluetoothPan.getDeclaredMethod("isTetheringOn", noparams);
        BTPanCtor = classBluetoothPan.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class, BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener.class);
        BTPanCtor.setAccessible(true);
        BTSrvInstance = BTPanCtor.newInstance(MyContext, new BTPanServiceListener(MyContext));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private BluetoothAdapter getBTAdapter() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        return BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    else {
        BluetoothManager bm = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        return bm.getAdapter();
    }
}

// Check whether Bluetooth tethering is enabled.
private boolean IsBluetoothTetherEnabled() {
    try {
        if(mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            return (Boolean) mIsBTTetheringOn.invoke(BTSrvInstance, (Object []) noparams);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public class BTPanServiceListener implements BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener {
    private final Context context;

    public BTPanServiceListener(final Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(final int profile,
                                   final BluetoothProfile proxy) {
        //Some code must be here or the compiler will optimize away this callback.
        Log.i("MyApp", "BTPan proxy connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(final int profile) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried using the same code but getting invocation target exception, while trying to invoke isTetheringOn. Registered both bluetooth and bt admin permission

Comment: Not working for me too... 
Not exception, but the value stay false.

Comment: Not working :-( Not exception, but the value stay false