# Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.bluetooth.IBluetoothPan.setBluetoothTethering(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, bluetooth, tethering

I was following the code in this thread/post: [Enable bluetooth tethering android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864670/enable-bluetooth-tethering-android-programmatically) (and subsequently, this post: [How to check Bluetooth tethering status programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299247/how-to-check-bluetooth-tethering-status-programmatically-in-android/22668259#22668259) ), and I encountered a roadblock. I'm using 
anirudh reddy's code. 
When I invoke the line

```
setTetheringOn.invoke(instance,true);
```

I get a NullPointerException. Here's the LogCat stack trace:

```
12-21 13:11:16.655: W/System.err(12738): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-21 13:11:16.655: W/System.err(12738):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-21 13:11:16.655: W/System.err(12738):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-21 13:11:16.655: W/System.err(12738):    at com.myname.android.bluetoothtetheringwidget.BluetoothTetheringActivity.turnBluetoothTetheringOn(BluetoothTetheringActivity.java:50)
12-21 13:11:16.655: W/System.err(12738):    at com.myname.android.bluetoothtetheringwidget.BluetoothTetheringActivity.onCreate(BluetoothTetheringActivity.java:27)
12-21 13:11:16.655: W/System.err(12738):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
12-21 13:11:16.655: W/System.err(12738):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
12-21 13:11:16.655: W/System.err(12738):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
12-21 13:11:16.655: W/System.err(12738):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
12-21 13:11:16.656: W/System.err(12738):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-21 13:11:16.656: W/System.err(12738):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-21 13:11:16.656: W/System.err(12738):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-21 13:11:16.656: W/System.err(12738):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-21 13:11:16.656: W/System.err(12738):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-21 13:11:16.656: W/System.err(12738):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-21 13:11:16.656: W/System.err(12738):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-21 13:11:16.656: W/System.err(12738):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-21 13:11:16.656: W/System.err(12738):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-21 13:11:16.656: W/System.err(12738): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.bluetooth.IBluetoothPan.setBluetoothTethering(boolean)' on a null object reference
12-21 13:11:16.656: W/System.err(12738):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothPan.setBluetoothTethering(BluetoothPan.java:337)
12-21 13:11:16.656: W/System.err(12738):    ... 17 more
```

In my `BluetoothTetheringActivity`, my `onCreate` method calls `turnBluetoothTetheringOn` method.

Moving forward, I went into debug mode (I'm using Eclipse Luna), and discovered something interesting when I got into `android.bluetooth.BluetoothPan.setBluetoothTethering` method: **the class variable `mPanService` was null**. This is odd because the code explicitly uses the reference to `mPanService`. Here's the code in `android.bluetooth.BluetoothPan.setBluetoothTethering`:

```
public void setBluetoothTethering(boolean value) {
    if (DBG) log("setBluetoothTethering(" + value + ")");
    try {
        mPanService.setBluetoothTethering(value);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Stack:" + Log.getStackTraceString(new Throwable()));
    }
}
```

I'm not certain how up-to-date this code is, but a site called grepcode.com has a page of `BluetoothPan`'s code: 
[android.bluetooth.BluetoothPan](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/bluetooth/BluetoothPan.java). In this code, `mPanService` is called `mService`.

**How can I ensure the `BluetoothPan`'s class variable `mPanService` is referencing an actual object before I try to invoke `setBluetoothTethering`?**

I may not be asking the correct question, so any constructive criticism on rewording my question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Android source code:
http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothPan.java
http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java

It is suggested to get Pan Proxy by

```
getProfileProxy@BluetoothAdapter
public boolean getProfileProxy(Context context, BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener listener,int profile)
```

And pass your ServiceListener as parameter to receive following event:

(1)`onServiceConnected`

(2)`onServiceDisconnected`

When you are notified when `onServiceConnected`, `mPanService` will be set, or else, `mPanServer` will be null. And you can do your preferred action during `onServiceConnected` and `onServiceDisconnected`.

But notest that, there is defect in current Android source code.
`BluetoothPan` will set `mPanService` as null prior to callback to your `serviceListener` when `onServiceDisconnected` is called, so it is possible that `mPanService` is null when you have done above items.